# Comparing char in a while loop --- condtion is never met

Tags: java, while-loop, char

So I have a really annoying problem which I am hoping one of you could help solve for me. This is a really simple program that prints my COMP science username in asterisks. I have attached a choice for the user - to either print the username in asterisks or simply print the characters.

I have constructed a while loop that validates the data entered by the user is accurate. The conditions for this while loop are never met - so it always loops through it no matter what is entered. I'm sure this is a really simple problem, just haven't really used chars before so can't figure out what I am doing wrong.

```
//===================================================== START OF MAIN
public static void main (String [] args){
    Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in); // Scanner for users input
    char usersChoice = 0;                   // Variable for users input

    System.out.println("\nWould you like to see the large letters or the small letters?\n    (Enter L for large, S for small!!)\n");
    usersChoice = input.next().charAt(0);   // Users Input

    System.out.println(usersChoice);

    //================================================= WHILE LOOP TO CHECK AUTHENTICITY OF DATA
    while (usersChoice != 'l' || usersChoice != 'L' || usersChoice != 's' || usersChoice != 'S'){
        System.out.println("\nWrong Input - Please try again!!!\n");
        usersChoice = input.next().charAt(0);
        System.out.println(usersChoice);
    }//end of while

    //================================================= IF (CHAR = L)  PRINT BIG LETTERS 
    if (usersChoice == 'L' || usersChoice == 'l'){  
        printU();
        print4();
        printJ();
        printA();
    }//end of if

    //================================================= ELSE PRINT LETTERS
    else{
        System.out.println("\nU");
        System.out.println("4\n");
        System.out.println("J\n");
        System.out.println("A\n");
    }//end of else
}//end of main
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `while` statement expression is always `true` since not all expressions can be true at once - you need the conditional `&&` operator

```
while (usersChoice != 'l' && usersChoice != 'L' && usersChoice != 's' && usersChoice != 'S') {
```

Comment: The OP's while loop expression will always be `TRUE` not false.

Comment: Thank you, all is working. Actually annoyed with myself for not playing around more and solving the problem. Young programmers hey?

Answer (score 1):

Your logical or(s) should be logical and(s), this

```
while (usersChoice != 'l' || usersChoice != 'L' || usersChoice != 's' || 
    usersChoice != 'S')
```

Should be

```
while (usersChoice != 'l' && usersChoice != 'L' && usersChoice != 's' && 
    usersChoice != 'S')
```

The problem with your `while` loop is there is no character that could meet the conditions. Consider lower case `l`, when the usersChoice is `l` it's not `L` so it wouldn't finish.

Comment: Thank you very much - I knew I had done something clumsy. Problem fixed -- all is working :)

Answer (score 0):

```
while (!(usersChoice != 'l' || usersChoice != 'L' || usersChoice != 's' || usersChoice != 'S'))
```

Just add an exclamation mark before your `while-loop`.

Your `while-loop` always do not work because:

```
if userChoice is 'l', it is not 'L'/'s'/'S' (expression is true)
if userChoice is 'L', it is not 'l'/'s'/'S' (expression is true)
if userChoice is 's', it is not 'l'/'L'/'S' (expression is true)
if userChoice is 'S', it is not 'l'/'L'/'s' (expression is true)
```

Your `while-loop` always evaluates to `true`